# оптимизация кода пандас

Tags: python, pandas

Считываю ексель файл и затем задаю новый столбец с названием имени этого ексель файла, итого код занимает две строки, а можно ли как то объединить это в одну строку?
Дело в том, что считывать буду порядка ста файлов и писать код в 200 строк на такую мелочь глупо, но ничего придумать не могу дельного...

```
DF = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Admin\ЗООПАРК.xlsx", sheet_name='1 лист', skiprows=12)
DF["CFO"] = "ЗООПАРК.xlsx"
```

Comment: Напишите функцию, которая принимает имя файла аргументом, возвращает датафрейм. Вызовите функцию для списка имён файлов.

Answer (score 2):

можно сразу использовать метод assign:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = r"dataset\Книга1.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(filname, header=None).assign(CFO=filename.split("\\")[-1])
```

df:

```
   0          CFO
0  1  Книга1.xlsx
1  2  Книга1.xlsx
2  3  Книга1.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

А все файлы в одном каталоге будут или нет? Если в одном, то совсем просто:

```py
for name in ('ЗООПАРК', 'КОНСЕРВАТОРИЯ', 'ЛЕСОПИЛКА'):
    DF = pd.read_excel(fr"C:\Users\Admin\{name}.xlsx", sheet_name='1 лист', skiprows=12)
    DF["CFO"] = f"{name}.xlsx"
```

Используйте списки (или кортежи, как у меня сделано) и цикл `for`, чтобы не повторяться (принцип `DRY`).